# Laravel Eloquent Collection and Query

Tags: laravel

```
 public function create() {
            $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            $makers= Maker::all();
            return view('maker.create', compact('makers'));
        }
```

What I wanted to do is how to pass the categories name into the view but the form will accept its id. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$makers` is a collection, so you need to use `foreach` to iterate:

```
@foreach ($makers as $maker)
    {{ $maker->id }}
@endforeach
```

**Update**

If you want to pass it to `Form::select`, use `pluck()` method:

```
$makers = Maker::pluck('name', 'id');
```

It will generate array, which you can use:

```
{!! Form::select('selectName', $makers, ....) !!}
```

Comment: I want to pass it to a Form Select with Laravel Collective

Comment: Oh, i forgot the pluck method sorry